# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un comando con privilegios de administrador con confirmación sin contraseña?

Tags: cmd, batch, windows10, línea-de-comandos

Estoy tratando de ejecutas el siguiente un comando que me abré la ventana de variables de entorno, pero cuando quiero modificar la variable path no me lo permite.

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

[image: variables de entorno]

Me di cuenta que si lo abro como administrador me permite editar. A partir de esto estoy tratando de hacer un comando propio (un `bat`) para acceder facilitar el acceso a esta ventana (y a otras más). Lo que hago por ahora es utilizar un acceso directo (con la opción de ejecutar como administrador habilitada) para poder ejecutarlo con los privilegios.

Lo vengo haciendo así debido a que no me solicita contraseña (se explicara más adelante esto).

El problema de esto es que debo llamar al *comando* siempre con el sufijo `.lnk`, por ejemplo, `panel-env.lnk`. Esto tiene dos problemas, el menor es se debe escribir siempre el `.lnk` lo cual es ciertamente incomodo, el segundo es que si deseas hacer un cambio, no podrías editarlo de forma comoda (solo podrías editarlo desde panel de propiedades).

Una alternativa a los sufijos `.lnk` es utilizar un archivo `bat` que llame al acceso directo. El problema de esto es obvio cuando se desean hacer varios *comandos* propios, muchos archivos llamadas y no es mantenible (por ejemplo, cuando se desea cambiar el nombre a un *comando* se debería hacer un doble cambio, uno en el `lnk` y otro en el `bat` que lo llama) además que la edición sigue siendo un problema no resuelto.

Esto lo aclaro ahora para no encontrarme esto en las respuesta de mi siguiente pregunta.

### ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un comando para que aparezca la ventana de UAC de confirmación?

He intentado usar los siguientes comando solo para probar abrir una consola con privilegio de administrador:

```
runas /user:administrador cmd
runas /user:administrator cmd
runas /user:Administrador cmd
runas /user:Administrator cmd
runas /noprofile /user:administrador cmd
runas /noprofile /user:administrator cmd
runas /noprofile /user:Administrador cmd
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd
```

El problema es que en todo caso me pide la contraseña de administrador, lo cual quiero evitar.

[image: pedido de contraseña]

Para dejarlo más claro, lo que busco es un comando (`runas` u otro) que me abra la siguiente ventana y no me pida la contraseña cuando quiera ejecutar un programa:

[image: cmd UAC]

Quiero lo mismo que se haría la poner el siguiente comando en powershell:

```
start cmd -verb runas
```

No quiero usar powershell debido a que tarda un tiempo considerable en cargar las cosas, es relativamente poco, pero lo suficiente como para no tomarlo como una opción al ejectuar comandos propios que pueden ser frecuentemente ejecutados.

### Requisitos:

- No es opción desactivar la seguridad de UAC.
- En comando puede no ser `runas`, pero sí nativo de Windows.
- No debe usar powershell.
- No debe usar accesos directos.
- No debe usar archivos `.vbs` o `.js`.

Saludos y gracias por leer.

Comment: Aclaraciones: eso que describes es imposible porque ni windows ni mucho menos linux lo permiten,  punto final,  haz pensado en que por algo hay una contraseña de administrador?, no puedes saltarte la contraseña de administrador para ejecutar archivos con privilegios asi sin mas,  el poder hacer eso seria un grave problema de seguridad de windows o linux,  incluso en linux para poder ejecutar xampp deberas escribir tu contraseña de administrador,  en windows es mucho mas comodo,  puesto que en windows es opcional ejecutar xampp con privilegios de administrador.

Comment: PD: ah pero mi windows no tiene contraseña de administrador,  no hay forma de que simplemente no me la pida si no hay una?, imagino conoces los bots... ten en cuenta que aunque windows no tenga asignada una contraseña de administrador, para hacerle mas dificil la tarea a los hackers de que se apoderen de tu PC windows y linux deberan requerir una confirmacion del administrador de alguna manera,  por lo que, asi tengas o no una contraseña de administrador asignada,  igual te va a pedir confirmacion, esto se hace porque los perifericos locales son mucho mas dificiles de hackear.

Comment: Y a no ser de que el hacker haya instalado hardware propio en los perifericos de tu PC para poder controlarlos,  es muy muy dificil,  por no decir casi que imposible el hecho de que un hacker logre hackear los perifericos,  por este motivo hay una confirmacion,  por que imagina lo que un hacker puede hacerle a tu pc y a tu informacion con privilegios de administrador del sistema?, puede hasta dañar tu computadora si asi lo desea.

Comment: Por cierto, creo que estas siendo un poco demandante con los requisitos, hay que pensar en que los unicos programas que permiten instalarse de manera automatica sin tener que pasar por el administrador son programas de instalacion oficiales, programas confirmados y de fiabilidad por microsoft, rucuerdo que cuando intente instalar visual C++, no me aparecia ejecutar como administrador por ninguna parte, simplemente me aparecia en vez de esa opcion, la opcion "instalar", pero esas son excepciones, son programas confirmados por la misma Microsoft.

Comment: Se que en tu caso no se trata de una instalacion de un programa,  pero lo que intentas hacer requiere la misma cantidad de privilegios que la instalacion de un programa.

Comment: yo sé que con powershell lo que quiero hacer se puede hacer con el comando `start cmd -verb runas`, esto lo podría hacer, pero quiero evitarlo hacer en powershell debido a que es levementa más lento que el cmd. Ahora voy a actualizar el post para que veas como se puede hacer en powershell y que no necesariamete es una vulnerabilidad.

Comment: Requiere confirmacion para ejecutarse?

Comment: sí y no requiere que coloque ninguna contraseña.

Comment: Exacto, es eso a lo que me refiero cuando dije "Asi no tengas una contraseña el sistema igual te va a pedir una confirmacion", yo me refiero es a que no hay forma de que no te pida ni confirmacion de administrador, ni contraseña, alguno de los 2 te debe pedir siempre.

Comment: sí, eso lo entiendo, yo solo quiero saber como _"evitar"_ la contraseña y me pida el otro tipo de confirmación (llamemosla el cuadro de confirmación) a través de un comando en __cmd__

Comment: Creo que acabo de encontrar algo de utilidad en esta pagina, haz probado esto?: https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/379807

Comment: Por qué no puede usar ficheros vbs? Piensa que en el mismo .bat podrías crear el fichero en una ruta temporal y una vez ejecutado, borrarlo. No sería válido algo así?

Comment: la idea es no depender de archivos/lenguajes ajenos a bat, pero es una buena sugerencia de todos modos. Gracias, realmente creí/recordaba que había una manera a través de un comando para realizarlo pero parece no haberla.